# Minimum permissions from user in phongap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a phongap app almost ready to be released,
The app gets data from a database (AJAX), shows the users location on google maps and stores a few strings in the users localstorage.

I built my app useing phonegap build and it all works great.

My problem is when I download the APK to my device I am asked for all posible permissions.
I unchecked all unwanted features in the WMAppManifest, and my config.xml shows:

```
<features>
<feature name="Device">
  <param name="wp-package" value="Device" onload="false"/>
  <param name="android-package" value="Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
  <param name="wp-package" value="NetworkStatus"/>
  <param name="android-package" value="NetworkStatus" /></feature>
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is in the config file but what is it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you edit the manifest.xml file?

Comment: from what I know the manifest is built from the config.xml.

Comment: where is the manifest located? As I wrote, I only found the WMAppManifest where I checked only the basic things the app needs.

Comment: in your project folder you can find the androidmanifest.xml

Comment: no such file in my project. from my config file I'm able to make a file with all features or none, but not a few.

Comment: Posting your complete config.xml might help us.

Comment: phonegap build gets only my config file, not the androidmanifest.xml. I upload the www folder with the config file. I guess phonegap build produces a new file. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the individual permissions in your apps `config.xml`.

First, disable all permissions.

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
```

After that, you can enable the required permissions one by one.

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
```

Just insert the feature(s) you need – the others can/should be left out.

Source: [PhoneGap Build Documentation (Features section)](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_features.md.html#Features)

Comment: When I use the setting to disable all permissions as you wrote and then build the APK, I am not asked for all permissions, but I still can't get the option to disable few feutures, its like all or nothing.

Comment: You disable all of them first, then enable the one you need. All in the same config.xml. It worked for me.

Comment: how do you enable them? maybe thats what Im doing wrong?

Comment: I edited my answer to show the available permission/feature settings.